# how to programmatically send business card messages to mobile phone via internet

Tags: api, mobile, vcf-vcard

Is it possible to send messages from internet in business card formats. ?  I need to send a contact to a mobile phone so that the recipient can save the contact easily.

using sms api s we can send sms but how to send business card files ?

In my project scenario I have telephone numbers of 10 persons which I need to send the numbers to another mobile phone in business card format.

Any ideas on how to implement ?

Comment: business cards are the vcard file formats for mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> vCard is a file format standard for
>   electronic business cards.    vCards
>   are often attached to e-mail messages,
>   but can be exchanged in other ways,
>   such as on the World Wide Web or
>   Instant Messaging.   They can contain
>   name and address information, phone
>   numbers, e-mail addresses, URLs,
>   logos, photographs, and even audio
>   clips.

More info on vCard at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard).

A vCard has a particular format, an example on Wikipedia is as follows

vCard 2.1:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Gump;Forrest
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
TEL;WORK;VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;HOME;VOICE:(404) 555-1212
ADR;WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;WORK;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:100 Waters Edge=0D=0ABaytown, LA 30314=0D=0AUnited States of America
ADR;HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;HOME;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:42 Plantation St.=0D=0ABaytown, LA 30314=0D=0AUnited States of America
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
```

vCard 3.0:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Gump;Forrest
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;VALUE=URL;TYPE=GIF:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:(404) 555-1212
ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100 Waters Edge\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
```

**A vCard received on a mobile phone is simply a SMS in a vCard format.**

So to answer your question

> I am using SMS API to send SMS but how
>   to send business card files?
>   Is it
>   possible to send messages from
>   Internet in business card formats?
>   I need to send a contact to a mobile
>   phone so that the recipient can save
>   the contact easily.

Yes, you can send a vCard to a mobile phone, just format the contact details in a vCard format and send it as SMS.

But be aware that the vCard format is different for different phones.
[Different vCard formats on different devices](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?119993-Different-vCard-formats-on-different-devices)

**Also See**
[3 Different formats to send a vCard](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?37786-3-different-formats-to-send-a-vcard)
[vCard message through a SMS message to various Nokia phones](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?13453-vCard-message-through-a-SMS-message-to-various-Nokia-phones)
[vCard via SMS](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?77679-vcard-via-SMS)

Comment: how to make an api call that sends the vcard ? Is it possible to construct such vcard programmatically and send it through ?

Comment: Which API you are using? Just creating a simple text file in the above mentioned format should work.