# Attach a vCard to MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, vcf-vcard, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to attach a `.vcf file` to the `MFMessageComposeViewController` as a share contact feature in my app. 
I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381938/send-location-information-or-vcard-through-sms-on-iphone?rq=1) and it is said that there is no possibility to send a contact info through message composer. I also tried setting the encoded string to the message body as suggested in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458211/1424174), which also didn't work. I don't know how it is implemented in the default message app as in the below image.

[image: Contacts info in the MessageComposer]

Can anyone suggest me how to implement this share contact option as in the default Contacts app of the iPhone? Any timely help is much more appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this method - (BOOL)addAttachmentData:(NSData *)attachmentData typeIdentifier:(NSString *)uti filename:(NSString *)filename

Comment: But the above method is available only in the `MFMailComposeViewControler` only na,.
I asked for the the same in the `MFMessageComposeViewController` buddy..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding attachment feature is added in iOS7 with the `MFMessageComposeViewController` class.
The method [– addAttachmentData:typeIdentifier:filename:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMessageComposeViewController/addAttachmentData%3atypeIdentifier%3afilename%3a) gives the answer where `typeIdentifier` can be set as `kUTTypeVCard`.