# AT Command to send Business Card (VCard)

Tags: command, at-command

I have developed my SMS solution using AT Commands. now i need to send Business Cards (VCards)   using AT Command.

I have searched alot but can't find the command for the above.

Can anyone help me out.

Regards,
Zeeshan Saeed.

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327462/how-to-programmatically-send-business-card-messages-to-mobile-phone-via-internet). You don't need a different AT command. You need to edit the SMS to be in vCard format.